# How to get a property from a plist

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, string-to-symbol

I am a newbie in Lisp.
I want to access a particular property from a property list with a string variable like this

```
(setf sym (list :p1 1))
(setf x "p1")
(getf sym :x)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### About cl:getf

Let Petit Prince's answer is right that [**getf**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_getf.htm) is probably the function you want to use here, but note that it can be used for more than just keyword symbols.  You can use it for any objects.  A property list is just a list of alternating indicators and values, and any object can be an indicator:

```
(let ((plist (list 'a 'b 'c 'd)))
  (getf plist 'c))
;=> D
```

You can even use strings as indicators:

```
(let* ((name "p1")
       (plist (list name 1)))
  (getf plist name))
;=> 1
```

However, that's probably not great practice, since **getf** compares indicators with **eq**.  That means that using strings as indicators might not be reliable, depending on your use case:

```
(let ((plist (list "p1" 1)))
  (getf plist "p1"))
;=> NIL
```

### For your example

In your case, you're trying to take a string and find the object for a symbol with a name that's string-equal (i.e., with the same characters, but disregarding case).  It probably makes more sense to **loop** over the list and compare indicators with **string-equal**.

```
(let ((plist '(:p1 1 :p2 2)))
  (loop 
     for (indicator value) on plist by #'cddr
     when (string-equal indicator "p1")
     return value))
;=> 1
```

And of course, you can wrap that up in a function for abstraction:

```
(defun getf-string-equal (plist indicator)
  (loop
     for (i v) on plist by #'cddr
     when (string-equal i indicator)
     return v))
```

```
(getf-string-equal '(:p1 1 :p2 2) "p1")
;=> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to `getf` is a keyword, and you have string. A keyword is a symbol that lives in the package KEYWORD and has usually been uppercased by the reader:

```
? (setf sym (list :p1 1))
(:P1 1)
? sym
(:P1 1)
```

So you need to use:

```
? (getf sym (find-symbol (string-upcase x) "KEYWORD"))
1
```

Comment: The second parameter to **getf** is not necessarily a keyword.  It's any object.  Keyword symbols are often keywords, but there's also a good usecase for making them *non*-keyword symbols from other packages:  it's less likely for indicators to clash.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: since the same numbers and characters don't need to be identical, GETF might not be useful for those...

Comment: @RainerJoswig That's right, and I gave some examples of it in my answer.  GETF isn't useful there, but it's still quite useful with non-keyword symbols.